# Why is an @Autowire null in a bean retrieved from ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader, applicationcontext

I have studied many other StackOverflow posts on Spring autowire issues. This question is not so simple as "don't expect @Autowire to work on an object you `new`".

I have a library that constructs objects from class names. The object classes must extend class
F. The library is not built with Spring. It accepts a class loader for resolving the class names. It is doing this:

```
     Class<?> someClass = Class.forName(className, true, classLoader);
     if (F.class.isAssignableFrom(someClass)) {
          Class<? extends F> fClass = (Class<? extends F>) someClass; 
          Constructor constructor = fClass.getConstructor(FMap.class, Object.class);
          F fobject = (F) constructor.newInstance(parameterMap, applicationContext);
      ...
```

The library allows some context to be passed in. Here I provide the Spring ApplicationContext.
A particular subclass of F has code like this in its constructor:

```
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext)context;
    X xbean = (X)applicationContext.getBean("xbean");
    S sobject = new S(xbean);
```

Class X is defined like this:

```
    @Component
    public class X {

    private final Y ybean;

    @Autowired
    public X(Y ybean) {
        this.ybean = ybean;
    }
    ...
```

Class Y is another @Component.

The `sobject` is able to call a method in the `xbean` (xbean is not null), but the `ybean` is null. Why?

I thought that Spring constructed and wired up the @Components at application start
time. I expected that using an object from ApplicationContext would
give me a completely built and wired up object.

**Updates 06/03/2020**
I added an @PostConstruct as suggested in the first answer. That showed that the object is getting constructed early in the life of the application.

I tried disabling `spring.devtools.restart.enabled` with no change in behavior.

I tried disabling `spring.main.lazy-initialization` with no change in behavior.

I removed spring-boot-devtools from my build.gradle with no change in behavior. However, the class loader being reported when the F objects and the Y bean are constructed is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`

We are running org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.6.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Y will only be autowired, when it is also present in Springs' application context. Verify that you actually have your component scan configured so that it picks up your Y component. you can quickly verify this by adding a post consturct snippet to Y.

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
   logger.info("Here I am");
}
```

If your logger prints nothing, Y is definitely not loaded into the application context.

Comment: Isn't spring will throw dependency missing exception?

Comment: not by default, but if you annotate with
 @Autowired(required = true), then yes.

Hm but I see where you are comming from, it is indeed strange that there is no exception on a missing constructor parameter, maybe @Autowired tampers with the default constructor DI.

Comment: The spring docs here [https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html] say (required = true) is the default.

Comment: I put the @PostConstruct logging in and I see it log on application start.

Comment: If it matters, the class loader being used to create the F class is `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader`

Comment: My mistake, the default for @Autowired beans being required is indeed true. Since Y is loaded in the context, you acutally have to share your real code so we can pinpoint the problem. It shouldnt be your library, since it only utilizes the Spring context.
How exactly are you trying to access the Y field of X, is your X component maybe proxied by CGLIB?